# get a div value from jquery

Tags: jquery

In the following div how can i get the value=12 value when the div is clicked

```
<div value='12' id='div1'>some content</div>

$('#div1').live("click", function(a) {
alert(this.value);
    alert($('#div1').val());  //doesnt work


});
```

Comment: $('#div1').attr('value') will do the work.

Comment: if you want to validate your code you could use the html5 (if you are using it as a doctype) you could use the data-xxx attribute and then use `$('#div1').data('xxx')` to get the value in your data attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use jquery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

try this

```
 alert($('#div1').attr('value'));
```

OR

```
$('#div1').on("click", function(a) {

   alert($(this).attr('value'));  //doesnt work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can keep away from using your own HTML attributes you'll run into validation issues, a better choice would html5's data attributes. This allows you to create your own attributes good for holding this type of data. For instance:

```
<div data-num="12" id="div1">some content</div>

    $('#div1').on('click', function(){
       alert($(this).data('num'));
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", '#div1', function(a) {

    alert(this.attributes["value"].nodeValue);
    alert(this.attributes["value"].value);
    alert(this.getAttribute("value"));

    alert($('#div1').attr("value"));

});
```

`live()` is deprecated, Use `on()` instead

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kXQe4/)**

Comment: `.live` isn't the same as `.on` (not in the way you wrote it) look at: http://jsfiddle.net/DdUKa/2/ to see that the alert stop working, to "port" the live function it should look like http://jsfiddle.net/DdUKa/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('#div1').attr('value'));
```

Should do the trick. All attributes of an element can be read and set via [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hTyum/)

The [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated(v1.7) and removed(1.9), so please use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead as shown in the demo.